# Python - reading and manipulating list from file.readlines() behaves differently in a for loop than in a while loop

Tags: python

I'm reading a list of all countries from a txt file. Calling `file.readlines()` results in a list of all of the countries with `\n` included at the end of each line. I intend to use `rstrip("\n")` to remove the character from each item in the list.

The intended result is achieved when I use this while loop:

```
file = open("countries.txt")
countries = file.readlines()
file.close()
i = 0
while i < len(countries):
    countries[i] = countries[i].rstrip("\n")
    i += 1
print(countries[:4])
```

Output: ['Afghanistan', 'Albania', 'Algeria', 'Andorra']

But it doesn't work when I use this for loop:

```
file = open("countries.txt")
countries = file.readlines()
file.close()
for country in countries:
    country = country.rstrip("\n")
print(countries[:4])
```

Output: ['Afghanistan\n', 'Albania\n', 'Algeria\n', 'Andorra\n']

Using a debugger, I was able to see that during the for loop, the `\n` is correctly stripped from the string, but the resulting string is not changed in the `countries` list.

I would really appreciate some insight on what mistake I made here. Thanks!

Comment: In your second example, you're applying the `.rstrip()` to a local variable, that you do not do anything further with.  You would have to explicitly assign the new value back to the list if you want to preserve it.  Writing the loop as `for i, country in enumerate(countries):` would give you both the index and the value, so that you could easily do the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake you have made here is that you are stripping the '\n' properly. But, you aren't saving it in the list, this code is basically updating the 'country' variable and has no impact to the list you are printing (countries) because it is not saving the changes. Here's what you should do:

```
for i, country in enumerate(countries):
   countries[i] = country.rstrip('\n')
```

This code should work perfectly fine!